# AngularJS - Closing Modal Window

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

My includes are:

```
bootstrap.css [ getbootstrap.com/2.3.2 ]
angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js from: [ angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap ]
```

I am using AngularJS and Twitter Bootstrap.

*From AngularJS I open the modal window as follows:*

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'resources/html/mymodal.html',
              controller: 'mymodalController',
              scope: $scope
            });
```

*My Modal Template is:*

```
<div class="modal">
<
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> 
  </div>
.....
</div>
```

**Question:**
The close [x] button is not working 
When I click on it, the modal does not go away. But when I press Esc - the modal vanishes.
So looks like ... data-dismiss="modal" is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using angular-ui's UI Bootstrap to open the modal

Comment: JeremyWeir: Pls note...i have added the includes(css/js) to the Question.

Comment: Do i have wrong combination of includes? I am a bit lost between twitter bootstrap (css/js) and angular bootstrap (css/js).

Comment: you must add `ng-click` to your `X` button.an in `ng-click` call a function for closing modal.

Comment: I would encourage upgrading to Bootstrap v3 if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the `data-dismiss` attribute is used by the bootstrap javascript (as I see you got the html source code from, http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals )

UI Bootstrap won't be binding to that close button because it isn't looking for that attribute, you need to add an ng-click and dismiss the modal like in the examples

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

**in controller:**

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

Modal template...

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: I have included: bootstrap.css [ http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ ], and i have angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js from: [ http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ] , is this a wrong combination? what do i need to get data-dismiss working?

Comment: You don't want to include the bootstrap.js if you are using angular-ui bootstrap lib. Use the ng-click handler to close the dialog like the example.

Answer (score 3):

In angular, there is a `close` method of `$modalInstance` to close a opened modal window .

Controller :

```
  $scope.closeMyPopup = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
  };
```

Answer (score -4):

I did it this way using jQuery with Angular:

```
jQuery('#YOURMODALID').modal('hide');
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use jQuery with Angular for this. Not best practice either. See the accepted answer.