# Closing the modal after i click on the button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, bootstrap-modal

I want the modal to close after i click on the yes button but now, it only runs the ng-click="" function. How can I close the modal after I click on the yes button?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmation!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Do you want to send SMS?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="smsAll()">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154726/angularjs-closing-modal-window) plz.

Comment: where is the controller for this modal where you have defined smsAll function ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code inside you smsAll method:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

This event is provided by bootstrap, to manually hide a modal.

Comment: lets say I close the modal on clicking Yes and I dont want to appear it again when user come to this page again. How would I do that. How can I control it with flag

Answer (score 2):

I have created a sample code. hope this will help you.

```js
 $('#myModal').modal();
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('ModalCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.smsAll = function() {
     alert('do your stuff');
     $('#myModal').modal('hide')
   }
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid" ng-app="myApp">

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmation!</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Do you want to send SMS?
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer" ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="smsAll()">Yes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

I added new attribute **[data-modal-action="close"]**.. based on the click event it will close the modal automatically

**HTML**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-modal-action="close" ng-click="smsAll()">Yes</button>
```

**Script**

```
$("[data-modal-action=close]").click(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
    });
```